# Deploying an Angular 2 app. Not sure what files to include

Tags: angular

I have followed the quick start tutorial located in the Angular.io page
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html to create an Angular 2 app and it's working fine.

In order to create the dependencies, I run `npm install`
This creates a bunch of files, and I assume only some of them will be needed for production.

What are the minimum amount of files I need to include to make the app work once I decide to deploy it?

I've looked everywhere but I can't find an answer. The only one that seems to work is if you use angular-cli which already has a command to distribute your app, but I prefer to stick to the other quickstart package.

Comment: Probably the person who downvoted me has no clue how to answer this. Very typical here.

Comment: Build as static files and deploy them to your http server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell NPM to just install non-development dependencies by using

`npm install --production`

This should be the ones, you can deploy on the server.

Also look at the [NPM Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: Thanks so much. Believe me that I looked everywhere but somehow I missed that!